# Is there a formal word for "new"?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

Imagine a new model is derived for a physical phenomenon and consider the following sentence:

> A new formulation is derived for the phenomenon of X.

Is there any formal or technical word for "new"?

Comment: "New" is dandy in any register. How "new" something has to be to be "new" will generally be evident in context.

Comment: Context will also dictate whether alternatives should be approbatory/neutral *(contemporary, present-day, advanced, recent, modern)*  or lean towards the negative *(unfamiliar, unknown, strange, unaccustomed, untried)*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers
Some of these words can't be used for "formulation" ; for instance, "a modern formulation" does not make sense, since "modern" usually used for some sort of technologies.
However, "an advanced formulation" is a suitable alternative.

Comment: @Sara: Nonsense! By which I mean what you just said, not ["about 1,380 results"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22modern+formulation%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books for the collocation ***modern formulation***. And let's not forget that it would be perfectly possible to say the ancient Egyptians used embalming fluids with "an advanced formulation".

Comment: @FumbleFingers
So we conclude that using an appropriate adjective is dependent on the kind of physical phenomenon. For example, for a chemical substance, we can use modern formulation; however, for a mathematical model we should not use "modern".

Comment: @Sara: I'm not sure of your exact context, but usually we refer to ***formulas*** (***formulae*** to traditionalists) in mathematical contexts (to mean "algorithms"). The related alternative noun ***formulation*** is normally only used to identify *a physical substance* formulated by mixing together various ingredients in proportions as specified by a *formula = **recipe***. Note that ***new*** can carry a *lot* of nuances, so much depends on which particular aspect you want to imply.

Comment: Do you mean is there another word that would be more correct?

Comment: @SamHarrington
Let say so, what's your answer?

Comment: here is my answer

Comment: does that make sense? if not please ask questions

Comment: @SaraWinslet For the academic papers context, the first word that came to my mind was *novel* (e.g. *A novel model ...*)

Comment: @DamkerngT. always sth new cannot be sth new ? you may present sth new which is not novel ! Maybe I am wrong !

Comment: @SamHarrington have the other authors/references derived any formulation for X before ? if so, it is not novel, it is just a new look on that phenomenon

Answer (score 1):

To me new seems to work best because its saying a new formulation (forming) is derived (obtained) for the phenomenon (existance) of X. so if they create something to obtain the existance it implize that it's new and purposly made for X. So if this wasn't new why would they create it to obtain it why don't they just buy it

Answer (score 1):

I've been reading a lot of academic papers recently so the answer is that the word ***late*** is closest in meaning to the word ***new***

Late research has shown that... And so on

Consider ***state-of-the-art***

However ***current*** and ***contemporary*** are used when the word ***late*** doesn't work in a certain context. But I assume that's not what you're looking for.

I don't really see anything informal using ***new*** either

Answer (score 0):

One alternative I've seen in many academic papers is "**novel**".

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/novel